# Sort array with 2 conditions

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a golf livescore leaderboard, but am having one issue. I would like to order the array by who has the lowest points, but also, if 2 or more have the same points, order those by which hole they are on.

My initial array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 1301
            [holes] => 6
            [points] => -2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 231
            [holes] => 5
            [points] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 3421
            [holes] => 6
            [points] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 46
            [holes] => 6
            [points] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 745
            [holes] => 4
            [points] => 7
        )
)
```

Now, then I do this to order the array by points:

```
$sortArray = array(); 

foreach($playersArray as $person){ 
    foreach($person as $key=>$value){ 
        if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){ 
            $sortArray[$key] = array(); 
        } 
        $sortArray[$key][] = $value; 
    } 
} 

$orderby = "points";

array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_ASC,$playersArray);
```

This orders the array by points, but as you can see, I have 3 players with 7 points but on different holes and would like to order those with same holes so the highest rank is the one on the lowest hole.

Hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Example:

```
usort($playersArray, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['points'] == $b['points']) {
        return $a['holes'] < $b['holes'];
    }

    return $a['points'] < $b['points'];
});
```

Change `<` to `>` to change sorting order.

Comment: this will sort the data in a descending order;

Comment: Perfect, actually :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

> This function will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

```
usort($score, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['points'] - $b['points'] 
        ? $a['points'] - $b['points']
        : $a['holes'] - $b['holes'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
function order_by_points($a, $b){
if ($a['points'] == $b['points'])

    // sort the higher points first:
    return $a['points'] < $b['points'] ? 1 : -1;
}
```